# Conversion of uchar array to uint8 type pointer

Tags: c, pointers, char, uint8t, pointer-conversion

I want to convert a array of uchar to uint8 pointer. As both are of 8 bits and value ranges from 0 to 255 so I do not think it should cause and issue.

```
uchar list[100];
```

I have to pass above list to a function which accepts pointer to uint8t. 
Can i pass it like this :

```
(uint8t *)list
```

such that it will not affect the value when i read it as uint8.

Comment: Should work, just give it a try.

Comment: Yes that's fine and correct, if you are talking about the standard type `uint8_t`.

Comment: this violates the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: Well, if you mean `unsigned char` , and unicode char, it should be OK usually. The standard says char should be at least 8 bits wide, to allow C compilers on machines where treating 9, 10, 12, 16 etc. bits as char is more simple, but my guess is probably you are not going run this on such machines.

Comment: Also, google strict aliasing rule, as ajay mentioned

Comment: i tried, it works fine just i wanted to be sure that it doesn't break in extreme or borderline cases.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `uchar` and `uint8_t` are not necessarily the same width ! Technically, a character can be 16bit wide. It is a rare, but it happens, especially in embedded world. So uchar *may* be not an 8bit type, but uint8 is *always* a 8bit type.

If `uchar` is indeed not a byte, then casting from `uchar []`to `uint8_t *` eliminates alignment restrictions. For platforms that do not support miss-aligned access (smells like embedded again!) trying to cast like this would be a bug. If you compile with `GCC`, add `-Wcast-align` flag to catch problems like this.